# How do I reuse the image that is already imported to the detail view of this RSS Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, rss

I have this code that receives the RSS feed and displays it into a Row, however, it does not carry over the image once the row has been clicked. How do I achieve this image transfer from the list view to the detailed view.

**This is the RSS Reader View**

```
package com.sieae.jamaicaobserver.rss.ui;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 *  This activity is used to display a list of rss items
 */

public class RssFragment extends Fragment {

    private RSSFeed myRssFeed = null;
    private Activity mAct;
    private LinearLayout ll;
    private RelativeLayout pDialog; 

    public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RSSItem> {

         public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                 List<RSSItem> list) {
                super(context, textViewResourceId, list);
         }

        @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
            View row = convertView;

            final ViewHolder holder;

            if(row==null){

                LayoutInflater inflater=mAct.getLayoutInflater();
                row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rss_row, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.listTitle=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.listtitle);
                holder.listPubdate=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.listpubdate);
                holder.listDescription=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.shortdescription);
                holder.listThumb =(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.listthumb);

                row.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.listTitle.setText(myRssFeed.getList().get(position).getTitle());   
            holder.listPubdate.setText(myRssFeed.getList().get(position).getPubdate());

            String html = myRssFeed.getList().get(position).getRowDescription();

            holder.listDescription.setText(html);

            holder.listThumb.setImageDrawable(null);

            //get Imageloader
            ImageLoader imageLoader = Helper.initializeImageLoader(mAct);

            //LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mAct
            //      .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            //View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rss, null);

            //ListView listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.rsslist);

            //pausing on scrolling the listview
            //boolean pauseOnScroll = true; // or true
            //boolean pauseOnFling = true; // or false
            //PauseOnScrollListener listener = new PauseOnScrollListener(imageLoader, pauseOnScroll, pauseOnFling);
            //listView.setOnScrollListener(listener);

            String thumburl = myRssFeed.getList().get(position).getThumburl();
            if (thumburl != "" && thumburl != null){
                //setting the image
                imageLoader.displayImage(myRssFeed.getList().get(position).getThumburl(), holder.listThumb, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {

                        if (10 > loadedImage.getWidth() || 10 > loadedImage.getHeight()) {
                            // handle scaling
                            holder.listThumb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        } else {
                            holder.listThumb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                    }
                });
            } else {
                holder.listThumb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            return row;
         }

    }

    static class ViewHolder {
          TextView listTitle;
          TextView listPubdate;
          TextView listDescription;
          ImageView listThumb;
          int position;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ll = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rss, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        if ((getResources().getString(R.string.ad_visibility).equals("0"))){
            // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
            AdView adView = (AdView) ll.findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        }
        return ll;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mAct = getActivity();
        Log.v("INFO", "onAttach() called");
        new MyTask().execute();
    }


    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            pDialog = (RelativeLayout) ll.findViewById(R.id.progressBarHolder);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            try {
                String weburl = RssFragment.this.getArguments().getString(MainActivity.DATA);
                URL rssUrl = new URL(weburl);
                SAXParserFactory mySAXParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                SAXParser mySAXParser = mySAXParserFactory.newSAXParser();
                XMLReader myXMLReader = mySAXParser.getXMLReader();
                RSSHandler myRSSHandler = new RSSHandler();
                myXMLReader.setContentHandler(myRSSHandler);
                InputSource myInputSource = new InputSource(rssUrl.openStream());
                myXMLReader.parse(myInputSource);

                myRssFeed = myRSSHandler.getFeed();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();                
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();    
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();            
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();    
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            ListView listview = (ListView) ll.findViewById(R.id.rsslist);

            if (myRssFeed != null) {
                MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(mAct,
                        R.layout.fragment_rss_row, myRssFeed.getList());
                listview.setAdapter(adapter);

                listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,
                            int position, long id) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(mAct,
                                RssDetailActivity.class);
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("keyTitle", myRssFeed
                                .getItem(position).getTitle());
                        bundle.putString("keyDescription",
                                myRssFeed.getItem(position).getDescription());
                        bundle.putString("keyLink", myRssFeed.getItem(position)
                                .getLink());
                        bundle.putString("keyPubdate",
                                myRssFeed.getItem(position).getPubdate());
                        bundle.putString("keyThumburl",
                                myRssFeed.getItem(position).getThumburl());
                        intent.putExtras(bundle);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                });

            } else {
                Helper.noConnection(mAct, true);
            }

            if (pDialog.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                pDialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //feedListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Helper.revealView(listview,ll);
            }
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.rss_menu, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.refresh_rss:
            new MyTask().execute();
            return true;
        case R.id.info:    
            //show information about the feed in general in a dialog 
            if (myRssFeed!=null)
            {
                String FeedTitle = (myRssFeed.getTitle());
                String FeedDescription = (myRssFeed.getDescription());
                //String FeedPubdate = (myRssFeed.getPubdate()); most times not present
                String FeedLink = (myRssFeed.getLink());

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mAct);

                String titlevalue = getResources().getString(R.string.feed_title_value);
                String descriptionvalue = getResources().getString(R.string.feed_description_value);
                String linkvalue = getResources().getString(R.string.feed_link_value);

                if (FeedLink.equals("")){
                     builder.setMessage(titlevalue+": \n"+FeedTitle+
                           "\n\n"+descriptionvalue+": \n"+FeedDescription);
                } else {
                     builder.setMessage(titlevalue+": \n"+FeedTitle+
                           "\n\n"+descriptionvalue+": \n"+FeedDescription +
                           "\n\n"+linkvalue+": \n"+FeedLink);
                };

                     builder.setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.ok),null)
                     .setCancelable(true);
                builder.create();
                builder.show();

            }else{

            }     
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the detailed view**

```
    package com.sieae.jamaicaobserver.rss.ui;

import java.util.List;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.sieae.jamaicaobserver.R;
import com.sieae.jamaicaobserver.fav.FavDbAdapter;
import com.sieae.jamaicaobserver.util.WebHelper;
import com.sieae.jamaicaobserver.web.WebviewActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 *  This activity is used to display details of a rss item
 */

public class RssDetailActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private WebView wb;
    private FavDbAdapter mDbHelper;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    String date;
    String link;
    String title;
    String description;
    String favorite;
    String listThumb;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rss_details);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        TextView detailsTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detailstitle);
        TextView detailsPubdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detailspubdate);

        Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();

        detailsTitle.setText(bundle.getString("keyTitle"));
        detailsPubdate.setText(bundle.getString("keyPubdate"));
        date = (bundle.getString("keyPubdate"));
        link = (bundle.getString("keyLink"));
        title = (bundle.getString("keyTitle"));
        description = (bundle.getString("keyDescription"));
        favorite = (bundle.getString("keyFavorites"));
        listThumb = (bundle.getString("keyThumburl"));

        wb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.descriptionwebview);

        //parse the html and apply some styles
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(description);
        String html = WebHelper.docToBetterHTML(doc, this);;

        wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wb.loadDataWithBaseURL(link, html , "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
        Log.v("INFO", "Wordpress HTML: " + html);
        wb.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(1, 0, 0, 0));
        wb.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        wb.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(WebHelper.getWebViewFontSize(this));
        wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url != null && (url.startsWith("http://") || url.startsWith("http://"))) {
                    Intent mIntent = new Intent(RssDetailActivity.this, WebviewActivity.class);
                    mIntent.putExtra(WebviewActivity.URL, url);
                    startActivity(mIntent);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                    Intent ViewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

                    // Verify it resolves
                    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
                    List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(ViewIntent, 0);
                    boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;

                    // Start an activity if it's safe
                    if (isIntentSafe) {
                        startActivity(ViewIntent);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });

        if ((getResources().getString(R.string.ad_visibility).equals("0"))) {
            // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
            AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        }

        Button btnOpen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.openbutton);

        //Listening to button event
        btnOpen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse(link));
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        Button btnFav = (Button) findViewById(R.id.favoritebutton);

        //Listening to button event
        btnFav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                mDbHelper = new FavDbAdapter(RssDetailActivity.this);
                mDbHelper.open();

                if (mDbHelper.checkEvent(title, description, date, link, "", "", "rss")) {
                    // Item is new
                    mDbHelper.addFavorite(title, description, date, link, "", "", "rss");
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(RssDetailActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.favorite_success), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                } else {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(RssDetailActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.favorite_duplicate), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;
            case R.id.share:
                String html = description;
                html = html.replaceAll("<(.*?)\\>", ""); //Removes all items in brackets
                html = html.replaceAll("<(.*?)\\\n", ""); //Must be undeneath
                html = html.replaceFirst("(.*?)\\>", ""); //Removes any connected item to the last bracket
                html = html.replaceAll("&nbsp;", "");
                html = html.replaceAll("&amp;", "");
                html = html.replaceAll("&lsquo;", "‘");

                String linkvalue = getResources().getString(R.string.item_share_begin);
                String seenvalue = getResources().getString(R.string.item_share_middle);
                String appvalue = getResources().getString(R.string.item_share_end);
                String applicationName = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                //this is the text that will be shared
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, (html + linkvalue + link + seenvalue + applicationName + appvalue));
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, title); //you can replace title with a string of your choice
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getString(R.string.share_header)));
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.rss_detail_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by does not carry the image? You are passing the url over intent as keyThumburl inside bundle, then what is the issue.

Comment: @AlokNair - When I add the the image to my layout.xml file, I have the stringid as lisThumb but it remains blank.

Comment: Can you please explain it in detail? I am not getting your point. Do you want to pass image to detail activity via intent rather than the keyThumburl?

Comment: Yes.... thats exactly what i want to do

Comment: You can pass it as a byte array and build the bitmap for display on the next screen, but using intent we can send small images like thumbnails,icons etc. Large images will give out of memory exception etc.

Comment: I would suggest you to use the method you have implemented at present i.e pass the keyThumburl and display the image on new screen as when needed by fetching from url like you did in first screen.

Comment: If you have any doubts on these, I can give you the implementation.

Comment: @AlokNair I would love to see the implementation. I'm still on a learning curve here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send Image via Intent as ByteArray or try loading from URL. Loading from URL is preferred as it will not bring OutOfMemoryException or any other issues while passing large bitmap images via Intent. If image is small, you may pass them via Intent.

The code below shows both the methods. Implement which suits your need or works in your URL case.

**Sender Activity**

```
//Download image from thumbUrl to bitmap
URL newurl = new URL(myRssFeed.getItem(position).getThumburl()); 
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl.openConnection() .getInputStream());

Intent intent = new Intent(mAct, RssDetailActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("keyTitle", myRssFeed.getItem(position).getTitle());
bundle.putString("keyDescription", myRssFeed.getItem(position).getDescription());
bundle.putString("keyLink", myRssFeed.getItem(position).getLink());
bundle.putString("keyPubdate",myRssFeed.getItem(position).getPubdate());

//pass image url
bundle.putString("keyThumburl", myRssFeed.getItem(position).getThumburl());

//sent image bitmap byte array
ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, bs);
bundle.putByteArray("byteArray", bs.toByteArray());

intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Receiver Activity**

```
   Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();

   //load from bitmap bytearray
   Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bundle.getByteArray("byteArray"),0,bundle.getByteArray("byteArray").length);        
   imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

   //or load from image url

    new LoadImage().execute(bundle.getString("keyThumbUrl"));
```

Create an AsyncTask to load image to ImageView from URL sent via Intent

```
private class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }
         protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... args) {
             try {
                  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(args[0]).getContent());     
            } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bitmap;
         }

         protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap image) {

             if(image != null){
              imageView.setImageBitmap(image);                
             } else{
              Toast.makeText(RssDetailActivity.this, "Image Does Not exist or Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     
             }
         }
     }

}
```

Comment: for some strange reason I am now getting a unhandled exception java.net.malformed error at this line

URL newurl = new URL(myRssFeed.getItem(position).getThumburl());

Comment: Try printing the url in logcat and see if it is working. Also try add a try catch to the url code part.